# Handling ReturnUrls on POST after Session Expires- MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-timeout

I Have  a MVC Application that uses a lot of Ajax requests to get and post forms within divs  on a page.However I stumbled upon the classic Ajax timeout  issue for  which I have fixed by creating a custom Authorize attribute  that just returns a 401 which allows me to redirect to the  login page via  Jquery( All well and good at this point).

```
 public class AjaxAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Items["AjaxRequestPermissionDenied"] = true;

            }
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

But When I do a normal server side submit of a form when the session has expired, I get redirected to the login form alright  but with form parameters in the Url i.e 
`Login/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fTest%2fComp%2fSite%2f4`.
So when I log back in , theres no way to insert the form back in the required div as this is a separate url  from the page that originally calls it.

The question then is, How would I handle such a situation so that  we are always redirected to the  default Login page or would it be best to redirect to a generac Timeout page  with a link to the Login page?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the ForsmAuthentication module that automatically redirects to the SignIn form if a 401 exception is thrown. Phil Haack [`blogged`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) about how you could override this behavior for AJAX requests.

So once you install the NuGet you could simply subscribe to the 401 errors in your AJAX calls:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/admin/secret/data',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    statusCode: {
        200: function (data) {
            alert('200: Authenticated');
            // Bind the JSON data to the UI
        },
        401: function (data) {
            alert('401: Unauthenticated');
            // Handle the 401 error here.
        }
    }
});
```

or do it universally for all AJAX requests by subscribing to the global [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) handler and inspecting the return code from the server and if it is 401 the session has expired and you could act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Darrin. I have got the Ajax bit sorted. The problem i have is with classic asp.net form submissions(via Submit buitton) that have values at the time when the session times out. I get a redirect to the login page  but it brings back parameters with it  which is the default behavior with forms authentication.I would like to exclude the return Url ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this article very helpful for my particular scenario .
I hope this helps others

http://markfreedman.com/index.php/2012/02/28/handling-session-and-authentication-timeouts-in-asp-net-mvc/